# What is the difference between OnLaunched event and resuming event in metro application?

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am trying to understand the application life cycle.

Scenario: I am launching a blank application; after that I am intentionally coming out of that app and opening a separate app. After some time I look at the Task Manager. The blank app appears to be suspended. Then I launch the blank app again (which was in a suspended state). At that moment, it has to hit the resuming event, right?

1) Why is the resuming event not firing? (Resuming event should be fired because the app is coming from the suspended state into the running state.)

2) Why is the OnLaunched event fired?

3) Is the OnLaunched event fired only when the application starts for first time, or also when being activated after termination?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *How* are you going back to your app?

Comment: i go to start screen and ping on the app(since i pinned the app to start screen).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much experience with Metro apps yet, but I'll try to answer:

Ad 1) If your application went from the Suspended to Running state (as in diagram in this [MSDN article on Metro Application Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx)), **resuming** event *should* actually fire. I made a few tests in similar scenario and it did. And btw, here's the best description of this event I found:

> When an app is resumed from the Suspended state, it enters the Running state and *continues from where it was when it was suspended*. No application data is lost, as it was stored in memory. Therefore, *most apps don't need to do anything when they are resumed*. However, the app could have been suspended for hours or even days. So if your app has content or network connections that may have gone stale, these should be refreshed when the app resumes.

Ad 3) Launch for what I understand is just a special kind of Activation (one of the possible entry points to application), which corresponds to transition from *Not running*->*Running*. Some quotes:

> When an app is activated, for any reason, the system sends the
>   Activated event.

and

> When the user switches to your **terminated** app, the system sends the
>   Activated event, with Kind set to Launch and **PreviousExecutionState**
>   set to **Terminated** or **ClosedByUser**. The app should *load its saved
>   application data and refresh its displayed content*.

Ad 2) If *OnLaunched* was executed and *Resuming* event wasn't fired, my guess is your app was in 'Not Running state', e.g. it was terminated by the system (Suspended->Not Running) before you re-launched it. I don't know why task manager might have not refreshed this information.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer this one:

1) but why the resuming event is not firing ? (resuming event needs to fired because the app is coming from suspended state to running state )

There is a debug button available for you to force your app into suspended state.  In the quick-search of visual studio search for "debug location".  This is a debug toolbar that you tap on the "suspend" button when you are debugging.  Once you go back into your app (give it acouple seconds before you go back in) then you should get the resuming event fired.

Comment: This feature is there because apps don't get suspended when running in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

ResumeEvent is not firing because you opened the app from the start screen or from its pinned tile. In that scenario, the app is treated as having been launched again. That's why the OnLaunched event was executed and not ResumeEvent.

To make sure ResumeEvent is fired, wait for 10 seconds after switching to other app, and then go to the top-left corner and bring the app back to the foreground. Make sure to wait the 10 seconds, before then Windows treats the app as running.